# How to divide the interval equally into 13 parts with Hive sql

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have this problem when I need to  do some statistics. Given a HIVE table which contains two columns, `min_price` and `max_price`. Now I have to divide the interval that made up by `min_price` and `max_price` into 13 parts (or some other number). 
How can I do it?

I've seen some answers using `connect by` in oracle but unfortunately not supported in Hive.
I'm very grateful if you can help me solve the problem.

Table that I got:(let's assume it only contains 2  rows.)

```
min_price    max_price
2834           3256
3054           3845
```

Results that I want to achieve:(13 rows for each row above, so 26 rows)

```
min_price    max_price
2834            2866
2866            2898
       ......
3223            3256     (13 rows)
3054            3114     
       ......
3784            3845     (13 rows)
```

*Only retain Integer part for upper and lower bounds of each part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You optimize this logic further. I just provided the idea and demonstrated that it works. See this demo:

```
set hivevar:parts_num=13; --define the number of parts required

with your_data as (--use your table instead of this
select stack(2,
2834,3256,
3054,3845
) as (min_price,max_price))

--query starts here
select min_price_calculated as min_price, max_price_calculated as max_price
from
(
select min_price, max_price, i, min_price+cast((i)*(max_price-min_price)/${parts_num} as int) as min_price_calculated, min_price+cast((i+1)*(max_price-min_price)/${parts_num} as int) as max_price_calculated
  from your_data d --use your table instead
     lateral view posexplode(split(space(${parts_num}),' ')) s as i,x
)s where s.max_price_calculated<=s.max_price
```

Result:

```
OK

min_price       max_price
2834    2866
2866    2898
2898    2931
2931    2963
2963    2996
2996    3028
3028    3061
3061    3093
3093    3126
3126    3158
3158    3191
3191    3223
3223    3256
3054    3114
3114    3175
3175    3236
3236    3297
3297    3358
3358    3419
3419    3479
3479    3540
3540    3601
3601    3662
3662    3723
3723    3784
3784    3845
Time taken: 0.449 seconds, Fetched: 26 row(s)
```

Comment: Excellent bro, my problem got perfectly solved, realy appreciate it !